# How to get rid of the horizontal bar in my website

Tags: html, css

A horizontal scroll bar appeared on my website and the page is now wider than it was.  The last thing I remember doing was adding a widget (to link a pic to another website) to the right sidebar of my page.  I removed the widget but the horizontal bar still remained at the bottom of the page and the webpage is still too wide.  Can you please help me in getting the page back to normal horizontal dimensions and  without a horizontal scroll bar.  thanks

here is the website
www.runningnurse.com

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?

Comment: No idea. Upvoted to counter that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the footer, it's too wide because the `div` child element of the `ul` (`ul` elements are only supposed to have `li` as their child elements!) is positioned to the left.

You have this HTML at the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul class="footer-links">
        <div style="position:relative;left: 119px; "></div>
    </ul>
```

Use this instead:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul class="footer-links" style="margin-left: 133px;">
        <div>...</div>
    </ul>
```

Also the fact that the HTML contains a lot of errors might give implications when viewing in in different browsers.

Comment: fivedigit you are the man!!!! I did exactly what you suggested and voila the site was fixed.. Thanks a million for helping me resolve this issue!! I'm still a novice in the website game ..i will research your solution to learn more from it..thanks!!

Comment: hey Fivedigit can you enlighten me on how did you figure out it was the footer that was causing the problem? thanks

Comment: I used Opera's development tools. All major browsers have tools like that however, which always include a DOM inspector. It integrates nicely with the page you're viewing. By just hovering either the elements on the page or in the DOM inspector, you can see the size of the element as a box, so it's easy to figure out their size and position.

Answer (score 3):

In your footer you have a div with inline CSS:

`position:relative;left: 119px;`

That's exactly how much the site is scrolling. An alternate style for that effect which would remove the scroll bar is this:

`padding-left:119px; overflow:hidden;`

Comment: AlienWebguy you are awesome, the problem was in the footer..thanks a million!!!  thank you for taking time to help me with this!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with your footer:

add `#footer{width:947px}` and it gets rid of the horizontal scrollbar for me.

Comment: locrizak thank you for the suggestion you were on the right track, it was the footer.  thank you for taking time to help me resolve this!!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to hide the overflow on the body tag.

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Use overflow-x

Comment: thanks j08691, the problem was on the footer. I tried your suggestion and it removes the bar in the browsers but in firefox you could still scroll the page to the right with the mouse.  In safari it works fine...thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 1):

As @j08691 Suggested, Use `overflow:hidden` and your problem would be solved.

Comment: thanks luditg, the problem was the footer...thanks for all the help!!